# Android - Issues with tabhost and aligning imageview and textview

Tags: android, android-activity, imageview, android-tabhost

Im trying to create a tab host as shown in the attached screen shot but having an issue with the icon image and alignment of text - the image needs to be aligned above the text but all attempts fail;

[PM For Image if unable to see link here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/01p5v9mjy3l6t49/gtryTHS-fC)

I've included some sample code but Im unable to force the image top align of the text - it only works if I increase the layout_height in the tab_indicator file to be greater than 66dip but Im restricted in space and the images supplied. If you cant see the image/link, the image is not forced above the text so it part of the image is behind the text!

tab_indicator.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="88.0dip"
    android:layout_height="66.0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1.0">

    <include layout="@layout/tab_indicator_portrait" />

</FrameLayout>
```

tabindicator_protrait.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tab_indicator_portrait"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="3.0dip"
    android:paddingTop="3.0dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"
        android:layout_marginTop="3.0dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="?android:attr/tabWidgetStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:textColor="@color/tab_indicator_text"
        android:textSize="12.0dip" />

</FrameLayout>
```

tab_host.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="0.0dip" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dip"
            android:padding="0dip" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

There are a few reasons why I've got it setup like this;

- the tab_indicator.xml file can also include a landscape file if i need to handle landscape differently i.e. further releases based on market feedback/testing
- allows the application to have a generic look and feel as I only want the icons to change when a user moves between tabs - had issues with tabhost in 4.0.4 and this seems like a cleaner way of handling it.

I've tried some code in my TabActivity to handle the layout size based on screen size;

```
private void detectScreen()
{
    Display localDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    if (localDisplay.getWidth() < localDisplay.getHeight())
    {
        int dips = 45;
        TabHost localTabHost = getTabHost();
        DisplayMetrics localDisplayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        for (int i = 0; i < localTabHost.getTabWidget().getTabCount(); i++)
        {
            View localView = localTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(i);
            localView.getLayoutParams().height = ImageUtils.convertDIPToPixels(localDisplayMetrics, (float)dips);
        }
    }
}
```

But again, changing the size of the layout DOES make the image smaller but not aligned with the text.

The manifest file also contains the following;

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"/>
```

Comment: I've tested changing FrameLayout to LinearLayout in the tab_indicator_protait.xml - this just removes the text and displays the image!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your indicator's code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="120dip"
    android:layout_height="64dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cntDesc" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="?android:attr/tabWidgetStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This had worked properly for me

Comment: That worked but didnt want to set the width/height manually. I think i need to edit the image and the 9-patch settings. Thanks for your help though.